# how to avoid an object being deallocated?

Tags: swift

```
static func appendMissingObjToArray(var oldArray:[AnyObject],newArray:[AnyObject]){
    for n in newArray{
        var isExist = false
        for o in oldArray{
            if(n.isEqual(o)){
                //exist
                isExist = true
                break
            }
        }
        if(!isExist){
            oldArray.append(n)
        }
    }
}
```

The above function is the append some data from newArray to oldArray.
when this function is done. And getting data from the oldArray, I got BAD ACCESS error. so I think it is due to the newly added object in oldArray have been deallocated and the newArray is released.

Any thing I can do for avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error: things like which line, what was in the various variables, which iteration of each loop, etc.?

Comment: It's important to understand that arrays in Swift are value type which means they are copied, not referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to declare your oldArray parameter as an `inout`. As follows:

```
//...
static func appendMissingObjToArray(inout oldArray:[AnyObject],newArray:[AnyObject]){
//...
```

You can then do e.g (note the ampersand `&` below:

```
class01.appendMissingObjToArray(&myOldArray, newArray: myNewArray)
println(myOldArray) // will contain the appended result
```

Done like this `myOldArray` (the passed array) will be mutated. So you may need to pass a copy of your original if retaining the original is important.